# How to connect the ends of edges in order to close the holes between them?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, edge-detection

My task is to detect the cracks on the soil surface and calculate crack's total area. I used Canny edge detection for this purpose.

Input image

[image: Input Image]

Result

[image: Here]

My next step is to convert canny edges to contours since I want to filtrate the cracks using `cv2.mean` and calculate their area using `cv2.contourArea` functions. On this step, I faced the problem. When I used:

```
canny_cracks = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny_cracks, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

It does not convert properly because of the holes the ends of edges. See problem here

[image: here]

My question is how can I connect the ends of edges in order to close the hole between them?

**Note**: I used contours detection without applying Canny edges. The problem is that contours detection gives a lot of noise and doesn't detect all cracks well. Or maybe I do not know how to find contours as canny edges do.

Comment: You can use [Morphological Transformations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-transformations) to connect the lines

Comment: Since the cracks are darker than the soil, you can also look into [Thresholding](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#image-thresholding) or [color based separation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#object-tracking), though it may not generalize well to other images or other types of soil.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used color based separation, it gives a lot of noise that is not easy to deal with. Regarding morphological Transformation, do you mean dilate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Morphological Close](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#closing). This closes gaps between white pixels. If you input your Canny image in the script below, you can try for yourself.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np  

    # function that handles trackbar changes
    def doClose(val):
            # create a kernel based on trackbar input
            kernel = np.ones((val,val))
            # do a morphologic close
            res = cv2.morphologyEx(img,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
            # display result
            cv2.imshow("Result", res)

    #load image as grayscale
    img = cv2.imread("KbMHp.png",0)

    # create window and add trackbar
    cv2.namedWindow('Result')
    cv2.createTrackbar('KernelSize','Result',0,15,doClose)

    # display image
    cv2.imshow("Result", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Starting from your 2nd provided image, here's my approach to solving this problem:

- Gaussian blur image and convert to grayscale
- Isolate soil from pot

  - Create circle mask of just the soil
  - Extract soil ROI
- Perform morphological transformations to close holes
- Find contours and filter by contour area
- Sum area to obtain result

---

We begin by Gaussian blurring and converting the image to grayscale.

```
image = cv2.imread('5.png')
original = image.copy()

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3,3), 0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
```

The goal is to isolate the soil edges from the pot edges. To do this, we find the outer circle of the pot using `cv2.HoughCircles()`, scale down the circle to grab the soil region, and create a mask using the shape of the original image.

```
circle_mask = np.zeros(original.shape, dtype=np.uint8) 
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.5, 200) 

# Convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
circle_ratio = 0.85

# Loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
for (x, y, r) in circles:
    # Draw the circle, create mask, and obtain soil ROI
    cv2.circle(image, (x, y), int(r * circle_ratio), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(circle_mask, (x, y), int(r * circle_ratio), (255, 255, 255), -1)
    soil_ROI = cv2.bitwise_and(original, circle_mask)
```

We loop over coordinates to find the radius of the circle. From here we draw the largest outer circle.

[image]

Now to isolate the soil and the pot, we apply a scaling factor to obtain this

[image]

Next, we fill in the circle to obtain a mask and then apply that on the original image to obtain the soil ROI.

Soil mask

[image]

Soil ROI

[image]

Your question was

> How can I connect the ends of edges in order to close the hole between them?

To do this, you can perform a [`morphological transformation`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) using `cv2.morphologyEx()` to close holes which results in this

```
gray_soil_ROI = cv2.cvtColor(soil_ROI, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(gray_soil_ROI, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

[image]

Now we find contours using `cv2.findContours()` and filter using `cv2.contourArea()` with a minimum threshold area to remove small noise such as the rocks. You can adjust the minimum area to control filter strength.

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

crack_area = 0
minumum_area = 25
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > minumum_area:
        cv2.drawContours(original,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 2)
        crack_area += area
```

[image]

Finally, we sum the area which gives us the crack's total area

> 3483.5

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('5.png')
original = image.copy()

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3,3), 0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))

circle_mask = np.zeros(original.shape, dtype=np.uint8) 
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.5, 200) 

# Convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
circle_ratio = 0.85

# Loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
for (x, y, r) in circles:
    # Draw the circle, create mask, and obtain soil ROI
    cv2.circle(image, (x, y), int(r * circle_ratio), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(circle_mask, (x, y), int(r * circle_ratio), (255, 255, 255), -1)
    soil_ROI = cv2.bitwise_and(original, circle_mask)

gray_soil_ROI = cv2.cvtColor(soil_ROI, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(gray_soil_ROI, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

crack_area = 0
minumum_area = 25
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > minumum_area:
        cv2.drawContours(original,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 2)
        crack_area += area

print(crack_area)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('circle_mask', circle_mask)
cv2.imshow('soil_ROI', soil_ROI)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```